# What is a better way to store a list of properties against one item in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, data-structures

I am generating a list of computers attached to a server. For each computer I gather a list of properties. I am new to Python and programming and am finding my solution rather clunky.

I was doing this with lists. I have a master list: `computer_list` and each computer is another list, with attributes such as status, date, profile, etc.

```
computer_list = [cname1, cname2, cname3]
cname1 = ['online', '1/1/2012', 'desktop']
```

The downsides of this method are becoming obvious the more I work and change this program. I'm hoping for something more intuitive. I looked into dictionaries, but that solution seems almost as convoluted as mine. The list within a list is workable but not readable once I start iterating and assigning. I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: use a Class to represent the computer and attributes to store its properties

Comment: Also, you might want to consider storing dates as a proper [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object, not as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make each computer an object:

```
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, status, date, kind):
        self.name   = name
        self.status = status
        self.date   = date
        self.kind   = kind

    @classmethod    # convenience method for not repeating the name
    def new_to_dict(cls, name, status, date, kind, dictionary):
        dictionary[name] = cls(name, status, date, kind)
```

Then store these in a dictionary or list.

```
computer_list = []
computer_list.append(Computer("rainier", "online", "1/1/2012", "desktop"))

computer_dict = {}
Computer.new_to_dict("baker", "online", "1/1/2012", "laptop", computer_dict)
```

Now when you iterate over them, it's straightforward:

```
for comp in computer_list:
    print comp.name, comp.status, comp.date, comp.kind
```

You can also define `__str__()` on the class to define how they are displayed, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Making a `Computer` object which stores fields describing the computer's properties and state is a viable approach.

You should read more on classes, but something like below should suit your needs:

```
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, status, date, name):
        self.status = status
        self.date = date
        self.hostname = name

    # (useful methods go here)
```

Perhaps you'd initialize `Computer` objects and store them in a list like so:

```
comp1 = Computer("online", "1/1/2012", "desktop")
comp2 = Computer("offline", "10/13/2012", "laptop")

computers = [comp1, comp2]
```